# How to remove rows in a spark dataset on the basis of count of a specific group

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe in Spark-
[image]

I want to filter the rows on the basic of count of **Person** for a particular **State**.
What I mean by that is, I only want to keep the rows for those **State** which have **Person** count of >1.

So the desired output would look like-[image]

The desired output would have rows for **State** S2 and S4 removed because they had **Person** count of less than 2.

It would be great if someone could help me with this.
Thanks in advance : )

Comment: You can count the Person over the window and filter the count greater than 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Count of Person over the window and filter out the rows as below.

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    ("S1", "S1_P1"),
    ("S1", "S1_P2"),
    ("S1", "S1_P3"),
    ("S2", "S2_P1"),
    ("S3", "S3_P1"),
    ("S3", "S3_P2"),
    ("S4", "S4_P1")
],["State", "Person"])

window = Window.partitionBy("State")

df.withColumn("count", F.count("Person").over(window))\
    .filter(F.col("count") > 1).drop("count").show()
```

Output:

```
+-----+------+
|State|Person|
+-----+------+
|   S3| S3_P1|
|   S3| S3_P2|
|   S1| S1_P1|
|   S1| S1_P2|
|   S1| S1_P3|
+-----+------+
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me out. You solved the problem that I was facing. :D

Comment: Any ideas how to adapt this solution when I want to group by two columns first and count the number of occurences per group?

Answer (score 2):

One alternative to the response of @koiralo would be to use a `groupby` and an inner join. Which approach `Window` vs `groupby` depends on the cardinality of the grouping columns. The rule of thumb: If the groupby results in a small number of rows it should be used. Otherwise if the cardinality of the grouping column is high a window function is the better approach.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    ("S1", "S1_P1"),
    ("S1", "S1_P2"),
    ("S1", "S1_P3"),
    ("S2", "S2_P1"),
    ("S3", "S3_P1"),
    ("S3", "S3_P2"),
    ("S4", "S4_P1")
],["State", "Person"])

states_grouped = df.groupBy(["State"]).agg(F.count("State").alias("count"))
states_relevant = states_grouped.filter(F.col("count") > 1).drop("count")

df_filtered = df.join(states_relevant, "State", "inner")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me out. You solved the problem that I was facing. :D